# Can I trigger a Shortcut from bash in macOS Monterey?

Tags: bash, shortcuts-app, monterey

Specifically, I want to be able to control Focus programmatically, I thought I could trigger it via a Shortcut but can't find anything.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [official documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/shortcuts-mac/apd455c82f02/mac), if you have a shortcut named "Focus", you can simply trigger it by running

```
shortcuts run Focus
```

I just [tested it successfully](https://i.imgur.com/PEn2GuO.mp4) on macOS Monterey 12.0.1 (that's zsh but bash should be no different).

Comment: Ninja'd.......!!!

Comment: Given the fact that the question was already up for two hours, we posting the answer within 10 seconds of each other is rather coincidental, yes.

Answer (score 5):

There is a `shortcuts` shell command, which executes shortcuts. See `man shortcuts` for details:

```
NAME
     shortcuts – Command-line utility for running shortcuts.

SYNOPSIS
     shortcuts run shortcut-name [--input-path input-path ...] [--output-path output-path ...] [--output-type output-type]
     shortcuts list [--folder-name folder-name] [--folders]
     shortcuts view shortcut-name
     shortcuts sign [--mode mode] --input input --output output

DESCRIPTION
     The shortcuts command is used to run, list, view or sign shortcuts. To create or edit a shortcut, use the Shortcuts application.
```